# Bullet not moving unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

At the moment I have a script that is firing a sphere, when i press the button which makes it fire; the pellet comes out but does not move across the screen, it just stays in a stationary position. whereas I would like it to move across the screen forward...

Script:

```
    #pragma strict

public var pellet : Transform;


function Start () {



}

function Update () {    

    if (Input.GetKeyUp("o"))
    {
        var pelletfire = Instantiate (pellet, gameObject.Find("pellet_Spawn").transform.position, Quaternion.identity); 
        pelletfire.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 500); 
    }


}
```

Thanks for any suggesitons

Comment: Is `Pellet` a proper prefab or did you attach it to an object already in your scene?  If the latter then Unity will drop an invalid cast exception blocking the call to `AddForce`.  I tried your code and it works just fine (pellet moves forward) on my machine, no changes.  Default rigidbody parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line with this-

`pelletfire.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 100,ForceMode.Impulse);`

For more details look at forcemode documentation in unity-

http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/addforce
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html

you also require a GameObject in scene with name "pellet_Spawn".
and your prefab should have a rigidbody attached to it.
and the script needs to be attached to a GameObject in the scene.
and set the prefab from the inspector.