# Bullet not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying my first test-game with Unity, and struggling to get my bullets to move.

I have a prefab called "Bullet", with a RigidBody component, with these properties:

> Mass: 1
>   Drag: 0
>   Angular drag: 0,1
>   Use grav: 0
>   Is Kinematic: 0
>   Interpolate: None
>   Coll. Detection: Discrete

On the bullet prefab, I have this script:

```
public float thrust = 10;
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

On my playerController script (not the best place for this, I know):

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") > 0)
{
    var proj = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

When I click my mouse, the bullet gets created, but doesn't move. I've added velocity to the rigidbody, which works, but I can't get it to move in the right direction. After googling around, it seems I need to be using rigidBody.AddForce(), which I did, but still can't get my bullet to move.

I've seen the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403562/bullet-not-moving-unity) solution, but this did not work for me either.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is there a rigidbody on your component?

Comment: @Jlalonde, yeah. There is, with the properties set as per the start of my question.

Comment: why do you use `AddForce` and not simply `rb.velocity = transform.forward * 100;`?

Comment: @derHugo. I've tried that as well, with the same effect; the bullet gets created, and stands still.

Comment: You didn't perhaps accidentally disable the script component on the bullet, right? If it is active, sharing a screenshot might give us a better idea of the situation.

Comment: @Serlite. Done, thanks for the suggestion. Is there anything more specific I can show you a screenshot of?

Comment: which one is the missing script on the GameObject `Player`?

Comment: @derHugo. Was left over attempts from earlier. Removed the missing component, warning is now gone, same result.

Comment: Ah wait a minute, you're working in 2D, huh? In that case, `transform.forward` is going to point along the axis that goes forward/backward toward the screen - i.e., it will not visibly affect the position of the object. Try something like `transform.right` instead.

Comment: @Serlite. I owe you a beer. Thanks! Struggling a bit with the dimensions.

Comment: Glad we were able to get the problem sorted! I'll write up an answer detailing it a bit more, so there's a proper resolution to question.

Comment: actually also .. you would use a `RigidBody2D` than ... than you would also notice immeditaley that you can not add a Vector3 force but only a vector2 force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with 2D in Unity, the main camera basically becomes an orthographic camera (no perspective effects) looking sideways at the game scene along the z-axis. Incidentally, the "forward" direction of a non-rotated object is also parallel to the z-axis.

This means that when you apply a force along `transform.forward`, you're sending the object down the z-axis - which will not be visible to an orthographic camera looking in the same direction. The quick fix here would be to use a direction that translates to an x/y-axis movement, like `transform.up` or `transform.right`.

As derHugo also mentioned in the comments, you might want to look into using [Rigidbody2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.html). There are some optimizations that will allow it to behave better for a 2D game (though you may not notice them until you scale up the number of objects).